# Visual Basic Excel create Checkbox in Code

Tags: excel, vba

I've added a button to an Excel file which, when clicked, reads a text file and populates a column with lines from a text file. I need to add a checkbox to cells adjacent to certain lines, depending on what the line contains.

Can I create components like checkboxes in code, and if so, how?

Any responses are appreciated.

Comment: i guess this is what you need http://analysistabs.com/vba/add-checkbox-on-worksheet-or-userform-using-vba/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While the link @Siva provided is certainly valid I just prefer to have an answer on StackOverflow instead of an external link. Hence, here is the solution you might be looking for:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub tmpSO()

Dim i As Long
Dim chk As CheckBox

With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
    .CheckBoxes.Delete
    For i = 1 To .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        If .Cells(i, "A").Value2 = "need checkbox" Then
            Set chk = .CheckBoxes.Add(Left:=.Cells(i, "B").Left, Top:=.Cells(i, "B").Top, Width:=.Cells(i, "B").Width, Height:=10)
            chk.OnAction = "runThisSub"
            chk.Name = "CheckBowInRow" & i
            chk.Caption = "CheckBowInRow" & i
        End If
    Next i
End With

End Sub
```

---

```
Sub runThisSub()

MsgBox "You clicked the checkbox " & Application.Caller _
            & Chr(10) & "in cell " & ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).CheckBoxes(Application.Caller).TopLeftCell.Address

End Sub
```

Copy both subs into a `Module` into your Excel file and change in the first sub

1. the sheet where the text is imported to (here it is `Worksheet(1)`),
2. the column where the condition can be found (here column `A`), and also
3. what the condition is (here the value in column `A` must be `need checkbox`).

The code will now look through all cells in column `A` in sheet `Worksheet(1)` and check if the value is `need checkbox`. If so, the code will automatically add a checkbox into column `B` adjacent to that cell.

If you click on any of the newly created checkboxes then the second sub fires up and will show you in a message box which checkbox in which row has been clicked.

Comment: That is absolutely awesome, thanks so much! May I ask what "Option Explicit" does?

Comment: `Option Explicit` is considered coding **best practice**. For more information read this: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/excel-vba/1107/vba-best-practices/3554/always-use-option-explicit#t=20160823142124572616 and also (if you wish to read Microsoft's thought on this) https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y9341s4f.aspx